# Spatial distance join between polygon and points using R

Tags: shapefile, r, attribute-joins

I'm figuring out how to do a Intersection (Spatial Join) between point and polygons from shapefiles. My idea is to get the closest points and those points that match completely inside the polygons. In ArcMap there's a function for match option named CLOSEST and they have defined by:

> The feature in the join features that is closest to a target feature
> is matched. It is possible that two or more join features are the same
> distance away from the target feature. When this situation occurs, one
> of the join features is randomly selected as the matching feature.

I have a function to intersect points into polygons. It was contributed by Lyndon Estes at the r-sig-geo list and the code works very well when all the polygons have filled all areas. The second case is known as a Spatial join distance and in ArcMap is know as INTERSECT when match_option is CLOSEST, as ArcMap does. So, you can modify the minimal distance between the point and the polygon when the area is not filled by all polygons, but I don't have access to ArcMap.

Here's the data (direct to my public ftp) and the function of the first INTERSECT:

```
library(rgeos)
library(sp) 
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
xy.map <- readShapeSpatial("http://www.udec.cl/~jbustosm/points.shp")
manzana.map <- readShapeSpatial("http://www.udec.cl/~jbustosm/manzanas_from.shp" )

IntersectPtWithPoly <- function(x, y) { 
# Extracts values from a SpatialPolygonDataFrame with SpatialPointsDataFrame, and appends table (similar to 
# ArcGIS intersect)
# Args: 
#   x: SpatialPoints*Frame
#   y: SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
# Returns:
# SpatialPointsDataFrame with appended table of polygon attributes

  # Set up overlay with new column of join IDs in x
  z <- overlay(y, x)

  # Bind captured data to points dataframe
  x2 <- cbind(x, z)

  # Make it back into a SpatialPointsDataFrame 
  # Account for different coordinate variable names 
  if(("coords.x1" %in% colnames(x2)) & ("coords.x2" %in% colnames(x2))) {
    coordinates(x2) <- ~coords.x1 + coords.x2  
  } else if(("x" %in% colnames(x2)) & ("x" %in% colnames(x2))) {
    coordinates(x2) <- ~x + y 
  }

  # Reassign its projection if it has one
  if(is.na(CRSargs(x@proj4string)) == "FALSE") {
    x2@proj4string <- x@proj4string  
  }
  return(x2)
}


test<-IntersectPtWithPoly (xy.map,manzana.map)
```

Sharing some ideas with Lyndon Estes, he told me this:

I think the easiest thing to do would be to put a buffer around each of the points (you could specify 50 m if it is in projected coordinates), converting them to polygons, and then your task becomes an intersection of two different polygon objects.

I haven't done this type of operation in R, but I suspect you could find your answer with the following functions:

```
library(sp) ?over

library(rgeos) ?gBuffer ?gIntersects
```

Maybe someone else who has a better idea on polygon to polygon intersects/overlays could suggest the method.

I know that this functions could help to achieve it.

```
library(sp)
?over

library(rgeos)
?gBuffer
?gIntersects
```

On the other hand, I think perhaps making the points bigger could help but I'm not sure!

Comment: Cross-posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825169/how-to-pick-up-the-information-for-the-nearest-associated-polygon-to-points-usin .

Comment: I think you want raster::intersect, as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173800/when-aggregating-points-by-polygons-with-spover-function-how-do-i-include-att)

Answer (score 4):

You could do polygon to polygon overlays using sp with rgeos. You'd need to load rgeos after you load sp.

```
>library(rgeos)
>over(polygon1, polygon2)
```

Comment: `over` is provided by `sp`, not `rgeos`

Comment: Got it. Thanks. What I wanted to say was that you need rgeos to complete some of the over methods.

Comment: Hi @R.K., the output of `over(polygon1, polygon2)` does not bring the ids of polygon1. How can I get that information into the output ?