# When aggregating points by polygons with sp::over function, how do I include attribute data from both the points and polygons?

Tags: r, fields-attributes, aggregation, sp

Data: Zipped `ea.ml1` shapefile can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ueo4aed3tjop55k/EA201507_ML1.zip?dl=0), and the country outline can be downloaded [here at the GADM site](http://gadm.org/download). I've been using the Ethiopia ESRI shapefile. [Branch locations are here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2sltvsru3t4m006/Branches_Africa.csv?dl=0)

I have a country shapefile with differently symbolized levels in it (identified as ML1 attributes [expressed as values 1-3] in my code, originally from `ea.ml1` object; ultimately ends up as `eth.clip.prj`). On top of these different ML1 values, I have plotted different branch office locations (`branches`; reprojected and clipped as `branch.clip.prj`). The code and map output are below:

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(grDevices)
library(scales)

setwd("D:/Mapping-R/Ethiopia")

#read in ML and Ethiopia shapefiles
ea.ml1 <- readOGR(dsn = "D:/Mapping-R/Ethiopia", layer = "EA201507_ML1")
eth <- readOGR(dsn = "D:/Mapping-R/Ethiopia", layer = "ETH_adm0")

#remove all unwanted columns from eth shapefile
eth <- eth[, -(5:67)]

#clip ethiopia to ml1
eth.clip <- intersect(ea.ml1, eth)

#reproject admin boundary and clipped polygons
eth.prj <- spTransform(eth, CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))
eth.clip.prj <- spTransform(eth.clip, CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))

#define color scheme for ml1 features
eth.clip.prj@data$COLOR[eth.clip.prj@data$ML1== 1] <- "gray"
eth.clip.prj@data$COLOR[eth.clip.prj@data$ML1== 2] <- "yellow"
eth.clip.prj@data$COLOR[eth.clip.prj@data$ML1== 3] <- "orange"
eth.clip.prj@data$COLOR[eth.clip.prj@data$ML1== 4] <- "red"

#read in total branch location csv    
branches <- read.csv("Branches_Africa.csv", header = TRUE)

#deselect branches without shares
branches <- branches[branches$share != " . ", ]

#transform branches data frame to spdf for mapping
coordinates(branches) <- ~Lon + Lat

#set initial projection info, Albers equal area
proj4string(branches) = CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
branches.prj <- spTransform(branches, CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))

#clip eth.clip to branches
branch.clip.prj <- intersect(branches.prj, eth.clip.prj)

#select city to draw buffer around
br.select <- branch.clip.prj[branch.clip.prj$City == "Addis Ababa", ]

#draw buffer (distance in meters)
br.buffer <- gBuffer(br.select, width = 250000)

#plot clipped ml1, eth admin overlay, branch overlay, buffer overlay
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0)) #set plot margins
plot(eth.clip.prj, col = eth.clip.prj@data$COLOR, border = NA)
plot(eth.prj, border = "#828485", lwd = 1.75, add = TRUE)
points(branch.clip.prj$Lon, branch.clip.prj$Lat, col = "blue", pch = 16, cex = .25)
plot(br.buffer, col = alpha("green", 0.25), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

For now we can ignore the buffer. What I'm interested in is counting which points (`branch.clip.prj`) exist within each ML1 level of `eth.clip.prj`. To achieve this in QGIS, I use the "join attributes by location" tool, which outputs a new shapefile + attribute table that neatly lists all of the objects and features of the branches AND the ML1 values that were pulled from the `eth.clip.prj`.

From what I've gathered, to count the points within each polygon, I use `sp::over`, listing first my points, then the shapefile.

```
test <- over(branch.clip.prj, eth.clip.prj)
```

This appears to work, but only gives me the attributes from the `eth.clip.prj` shapefile:

```
head(test)
  ML1 ID_0 ISO NAME_ENGLI NAME_ISO  COLOR
1   1   74 ETH   Ethiopia ETHIOPIA   gray
2   2   74 ETH   Ethiopia ETHIOPIA yellow
3   2   74 ETH   Ethiopia ETHIOPIA yellow
4   3   74 ETH   Ethiopia ETHIOPIA orange
5   1   74 ETH   Ethiopia ETHIOPIA   gray
6   3   74 ETH   Ethiopia ETHIOPIA orange
```

I need the attributes from `branch.clip.prj` included so that I can ultimately create a CSV that reflects all of the data (so, in this case, all of the branch office data + which ML1 zone each office falls into). I figure I can add these attributes manually as follows, but with 5-10 different attributes in `branch.clip.prj`, it seems clunky:

```
test$City <- branch.clip.prj$City
test$share <- branch.clip.prj$share
#add for all needed attributes, etc.
```

Sorry this got a bit wordy. So, my ultimate question is: how can I efficiently keep all of the data from my point objects when I aggregate them by polygons with the sp::over function?

Comment: The answer is in this post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171856/spatial-join-in-r/172200#172200

Comment: Hi @JeffreyEvans, could you clarify a bit for me? I'm not understanding how/which part of that answer applies to my question. It seems like a completely different question to me (points-in-polygon analysis vs. join attributes by location), but I'm having a hard time understanding any of the link that you've provided. Is my solution to use `tapply` in some way?

Comment: The functions spatialEco::point.in.poly or raster::intersect both retain associated attributes. The values (say, mean or count) can then be aggregated using tapply eg., for point counts per polygon: tapply(intersect.points$y, intersect.points$PolyID, FUN=length)

Comment: OH, okay, I see now. So I need to use `raster::intersect` rather than `sp::over`? Sheesh, as soon as I seem to figure out one problem in R, it gives me 3 more! Hats off to all of you R mapping aficionados. :)

Comment: Also, look at one of the linked answers that explains the workflow you are after and the use of tapply to aggregate the point values to the polygons: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137621/join-spatial-point-data-to-polygons-in-r/137629#13762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by JeffreyEvans, the use of `sp::over` was the problem. By using `raster::intersect` instead, the output included attributes of both point and polygon data.