# Creating custom discrete color scheme for polygon attributes in ggplot2

Tags: polygon, r, ggplot2

**Data:** Zipped `ea.ml1` shapefile can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ueo4aed3tjop55k/EA201507_ML1.zip?dl=0), and the country outline can be downloaded [here at the GADM site](http://gadm.org/download). I've been using the Ethiopia shapefile.

As per suggestions on [How do I plot points as graduated/proportional circles in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173984), I have decided to try to transform my ongoing map project/test to `ggplot2` for ease of use. You can check out my full original non-ggplot code [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173800/when-aggregating-points-by-polygons-with-spover-function-how-do-i-include-att?noredirect=1#comment260234_173800). I have done a tiny bit of mapping with `ggplot2` in the past, so I'm somewhat familiar with it, but I've certainly not mastered it. I'm wondering how to change/customize my color scheme for the `ML1` attributes of my Ethiopia polygon. It should look like this (which I did with base plot functions, as seen in my linked code):
[image]

Using [this brief tutorial](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles) from GitHub, I managed to modify my code a bit to create this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)
library(plyr)

setwd("D:/Mapping-R/Ethiopia")

ea.ml1 <- readOGR(dsn = "D:/Mapping-R/Ethiopia", layer = "EA201507_ML1")
eth <- readOGR(dsn = "D:/Mapping-R/Ethiopia", layer = "ETH_adm0")

#remove all unwanted columns from eth shapefile
eth <- eth[, -(2:67)]

#define color scheme for ml1 & ml2 features
ea.ml1@data$COLOR[ea.ml1@data$ML1 == 1] <- "gray"
ea.ml1@data$COLOR[ea.ml1@data$ML1 == 2] <- "yellow"
ea.ml1@data$COLOR[ea.ml1@data$ML1 == 3] <- "orange"
ea.ml1@data$COLOR[ea.ml1@data$ML1 == 4] <- "red"

#clip ethiopia to ml1 background
eth.clip1 <- intersect(ea.ml1, eth)

#identifies attribute rows, converts to data frame, joins points to attributes
eth.clip1@data$id <- rownames(eth.clip1@data)
eth.f <- fortify(eth.clip1, region = "id")
eth.df <- join(eth.f, eth.clip1@data, by = "id")


ggplot(eth.df) + 
  aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = ML1) + 
  geom_polygon() + 
  geom_path(color="white") +
  coord_equal()
```

which resulted in this:
[image]

How do I customize my `ggplot2` color scheme (which is actually defined in the code, not sure if that's useful or not) to match the first map image that I posted (where an ML value of 1 is gray, 2 is yellow, etc.)? The linked tutorial simply lists its color scheme as "Utah Ecoregion" with no details about where it came from/what it looks like. I also tried the solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430467/custom-color-in-a-mappolygons-by-ggplot-in-r-and-plot-a-legend) to no avail; R just spit nonsensical errors at me.

```r
 ggplot(eth.df) + 
  aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = ML1) + 
  geom_polygon() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = (1 = "gray", 2 = "yellow", 3 = "orange", 4 = "red")) + 
  geom_path(color="white") +
  coord_equal()
```

gives me these errors:

> Error: unexpected ',' in: "  geom_polygon() + scale_fill_manual(values = (1 = "gray","

> Error in geom_path(color = "white") + coord_equal() : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

So, how do I customize the color scheme without screwing everything else up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a chat with @MLavoie, we solved the issue by changing the data type of my `ML1` attributes from an integer to factor and adding a c() to properly format the list of colors. New code should look like this:

```r
ggplot(eth.df) + 
  aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = factor(ML1)) + 
  geom_polygon() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray", "yellow", "orange", "red")) + 
  geom_path(color="white") +
  coord_equal()
```

Or, alternatively:

```r
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = eth.df, aes(long, lat, group = group, fill = factor(ML1))) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray", "yellow", "orange", "red"))
```

R was registering my discrete `ML1` values as continuous, hence the continuous legend/color scheme shown in my question. By changing that to a factor (which could also have been done prior to implementing the ggplot code), I was able to tweak the code to get what I needed.